# Override ListBoxItem default OnMouseOver Background style effect

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have come across a lot of different examples about how to do this but none seem to work for me. I have a ListBox which has a list of items. Every time you hover over the an item in the list there is a transparent background and a border around the item. I want to get rid of this. This is what I have tried;

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="SitesListBox_MouseDown"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The text colour changes fine but the Background and Border is not affected

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the transparent background and border or do you want to set it? your wording is a little confusing

Comment: Do you even need a ListBox. Handling MouseDown on ListBoxItems looks like you're not using the standard selection behavior. Maybe just use an ItemsControl.

Comment: @MattBeldon I want to get rid of the background and border. But it would be nice to learn how to change them as well.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want, but it seems to have the desired effect

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="SitesListBox_MouseDown"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```